# Translation in multipage application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am working on **hybrid multipage application**. My problem is the dropdown list **select option** is not responsive or i am able to click it but it is responsive or works when i remove the **pageload block**.

```
var pagesHistory = [];
var currentPage = {};
var path = "";
var busyIndicator = null;


function wlCommonInit(){

    busyIndicator = new WL.BusyIndicator( null, {text : ''});

    // Special case for Windows Phone 8 only.
    if (WL.Client.getEnvironment() == WL.Environment.WINDOWS_PHONE_8) {
        path = "/www/default/";
    }

    $('#languages').bind('change', languageChanged);
     var locale = WL.App.getDeviceLocale();
        var lang = WL.App.getDeviceLanguage();
        WL.Logger.debug(">> Detected locale: " + locale);
        WL.Logger.debug(">> Detected language: " + lang);

        if (locale.indexOf("en")!=-1) languageChanged("english");
        if (locale.indexOf("ar")!=-1) languageChanged("arabic");
    function languageChanged(lang) {
        if (typeof(lang)!="string")
            lang = $("#languages").val();

        switch (lang){
            case "english":
                setEnglish();
                break;
            case "arabic":
                setArabic();
                break;
        }

        if ($("#languages").val()=="arabic") 
            $("#wrapper").css({direction: 'rtl'});
        else 
            $("#wrapper").css({direction: 'ltr'});
        $("#loginusername").html(Messages.loginusername);   
        $("#loginpassword").html(Messages.loginpassword);
        $("#actionsLabel").html(Messages.actionsLabel);

    }
    $("#pageload").load(path + "pages/loginpage.html", function(){
        $('#loginwrapper').hide();
        $.getScript(path + "js/loginpage.js", function() {

            if (currentPage.init) {
                currentPage.init();
            }
                        $('#loginwrapper').fadeIn(5000);

        });
    });

}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>hrapp</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
            <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>

        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="w1wap">
<label for="languages" id="actionsLabel" class="translate"></label>
            <select id="languages">
                <option value="" selected="selected">--Select--</option>
                <option value="english" id="englishLanguage" class="translate"></option>
                <option value="arabic" id="arabicLanguage" class="translate"></option>
            </select>
            </div>  

            <div id="pageload">
            </div>

            <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
            <script src="js/main.js"></script>
            <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Preview your application in Chrome with the developer console open and refresh the window. What error do you see when you click the button that does not work? I am guessing that you should bind your button on the global scope to make sure it is accessible.

Comment: @IdanAdar i dont see any error in chrome dev and again my problem is **i cant able to click the select dropdown list itself** its like its present but hidden scenario

Comment: Do you have a complete project you can provide?

Comment: possible but my project contains more than 5 html pages and 15 adapters.

Comment: Then I suggest that you will create a new project that contains only the problematic section to ease the debugging.

Comment: ok will create and ping u afterwards thanks